# What is the name of the plant with the down-falling light purple leaves?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I've seen this flower in Scotland in August 2015:

[image]

What is the name of that flower?

To help people google it:

The plant has light purple leaves with some white spots. On those white spots are dark purple points. It is sometimes quite high (about 1.70m I guess). The bloom points downwards.

Comment: I'm asking this question because I would like to upload the photo on Wikipedia Commons. And for personal curiosity.

Comment: The common name in English is "foxglove". Note that they are poisonous.

Comment: Wow beautiful but do you telling that bright purple big things? they're NOT leaves. it is flower's corolla where petals fused and formed a bell-shaped structure. The 2-lipped 'personate' corolla with specialized abaxial surface ('throat') (here with dots and a tongue like shape) is a common characteristic of [scrophulariaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrophulariaceae), or the [snapdragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antirrhinum_majus)'s family. It seems to be [*Digitalis* sp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitalis) of that family (however wikipedia shows now shifted to plantaginaceae)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a *[Digitalis purpurea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitalis_purpurea)*

From the wikipedia page:
[image: Wiki Flower Close Up]